Why RTK Query's createApi produces "all 3 hooks need to be provided" error?
I have been working on a redux+ React Native legacy project, hundreds of reducers. I want to implement RTK query. I have written a very simple test example already integrated in the main project.
By just introducing the "createApi" function from RTK Query, it fails to compile with a message that say "Error: When using custom hooks for context, all 3 hooks need to be provided: useDispatch, useSelector, useStore.
Hook useDispatch was either not provided or not a function., js engine: hermes"
If I remove the createApi, everything works just fine.
I have tried several ways of implementing RTKQ, small variations, but whenever I add the createApi everything gets broken.
Just to mention it, The testbed is a barebone react native app, just to make RTKQ compile. I am aware I am not including pokemonApi  into the reducers, this is the simplest example I could come off with
This is the small code and my dependencies I have.
"react": "18.2.0",
"expo": "~51.0.4",
"react-native": "0.74.1",
"react-redux": "^6.0.1",
"redux": "^4.0.5",
"redux-form": "^8.1.0",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",

Old redux reducers here:
[......]
export default combineReducers({
  form: formReducer, //redux-form
  movements: movementsReducer,
[......]

import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'
import {  configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import reducers from './lib/reducers'

export const pokemonApi = createApi({ 
  reducerPath: 'pokemonApi', 
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/' }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getPokemonByName: builder.query<string, string>({
      query: (name) => `pokemon/${name}`,
    }),
  }),
})

const store = configureStore({ reducer: {  reducers }}
)
export default store

Main App
<Provider store={store}>
<App/>
[......]

I tried all kind of variations like not using combineReducer.
I tried the same test case in a just created RN project and it works, even with the same dependencies.

You are using an older version of Redux, and a very old version of React-Redux. Current is v5.0.1 and v9.1.2 respectively, so you may consider updating them. What version of Redux-Toolkit are you using? If you are using RTK then it ships with Thunk middleware by default so there's no need for redux-thunk as a project dependency. You don't appear to add your API slice's reducer to the store either. Lots of issues as far as I can see from the code you've shared, more than one specific issue to be addressed in SO's QnA format here. Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve]?

What @DrewReese said - your version of react-redux is so old that it didn't come with hooks yet, so there is no way for RTK Query to build on top of those.

Please upgrade from React-Redux v6 immediately! That version was unfortunately flawed, and you should at least upgrade to v7 right now.  (Ideally upgrade to v9, since you're on React 18.)

Thank you very much Drew, Phry, markerikson ! Guys, you hit the nail, I had just too old versions running! Upgraded dependencies and it started to run just fine! The old redux and its hundreds of reducers are all working just fine. Thank God it comes with retro-compatibility
